# How to get ID's of Self Referencing Table?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table that is setup similar to:

```
MyTable
Id        INT
Name      VARCHAR
ParentId  INT
```

Now lets say the data in this table looks like:

```
1  AAA  NULL
2  BBB  1
3  CCC  2
4  DDD  1
5  EEE  4
6  FFF  NULL
```

How can I write a function that will take an id (int) and return a table of IDs of ALL the possible children to that parent?

For example I would call SomeFunction(1) and expect to get:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Was able to write a function that would work but only if the children didn't same the same parent, however I need to be able to support that scenario.

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a recursive cte.

```
with children as 
(select id as child, parentid as parent
 from mytable
 where parentid is null
 union all
 select m.id, coalesce(c.parent,m.parentid) 
 from mytable m
 join children c on m.parentid=c.child
)
select child
from children
where parent = 1
```

[**`Try the Demo`**](http://rextester.com/IHBIX33273)

Answer (score 0):

A recursive CTE is the way to go.  A simpler version for all children of a particular id is:

```
with children as (
      select id 
      from mytable
      where id = 1
      union all
      select m.id 
      from mytable m join
           children c
           on m.parentid = c.id
     )
select *
from children
```